# Files in .local/share/gvfs-metadata in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

Is it okay to remove files in Files in `.local/share/gvfs-metadata` in Ubuntu?

For some reason, it is now up to 1.3 GB in my `home` directory?

Answer (score 3):

This is the Gnome Virtual Files System. All the reports I've read suggest you can delete the contents with no ill effect. Note that parts of the folder may not really be taking up the space they are reporting, as they represent virtual filesystems.

Answer (score 2):

I just do this. I delete all files inside `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata`

No I can safely open nautilus without making the CPU working 100%. No other strange effect so far. The system still running well.